# UIImagePickerController not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to show a UIImagePickerController from a button click. When I click the button, I get a SIGABRT at the line:

```
[self presentModalViewController:camera animated:YES];
```

from the code block:

```
camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[camera setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[camera setDelegate:self.view];
camera.showsCameraControls = NO;
camera.navigationBarHidden = YES;
camera.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
camera.toolbarHidden = YES;
camera.cameraOverlayView = bottomArrow;
[self presentModalViewController:camera animated:YES];
```

where `camera` is the name of the `UIImagePickerController` defined as such:

```
UIImagePickerController *camera;
```

in the `@interface`.
My interface declaration is:

```
@interface cameraViewController : UIViewController  <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The answers to this post point out some likely solutions, but if these don't work something else I can think of could be that if you are building on an iOS 6 deployment target `presentModalViewController` is depreciated. You should be using `presentViewController:animated` instead.

Comment: The `presentViewController:animated` also has `void^(completion)`. What do I do for the `completion`?

Comment: Pass nil if you don't want to specify a completion handler.

Comment: I used @Vikings method and it worked for me, but thank you for your help anyways. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the both the Navigation Controller Delegate and the Image Picker Controller Delegate.  The Image Picker is actually a Navigation Controller, which is why you have to implement its delegate.

```
 @interface YourViewController : UITableViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Also, set the delegate correctly, not to the view, but the View Controller.

```
camera.delegate = self;
```

The delegate needs to be set to the View Controller, and not the View Controller's View.

Check out the code below:

(1) You do not need to hide the navigation bar, because there is not one

(2) You do not need to hide the toolbar, because there is not one

(3) You do not need to specify wantsFullScreenLayout, because a Modal View Controller will always take up the full screen

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
// Comment out the line below to make sure it is not causing a problem.
// This just expects a view, so if bottomArrow is a view you should be fine
picker.cameraOverlayView = bottomArrow;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Also, I did not realize you were loading this code in viewDidLoad, this will crash, because the View Controller itself is not finished it's transition, so you cannot begin another transition.  Instead use viewDidAppear for the same effect:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    // Place code here
}
```

Comment: I tried all this, and like @amit said, I put the above code in an `IBAction`, but I get the error: `[__NSCFString superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147170'`

Answer (score 2):

Besides the good point made by @Vikings, always check if your device has a camera before trying to use it:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController
     isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    [camera setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
} else {
    [camera setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your code in viewDidLoad create one IBAction and put your code inside that function.

and set delegate to your view controller. and in .h file make sure that your wrote

```
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

[camera setDelegate : self];
```